# SQL0601N The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name "DJANGO_MIGRATIONS" of type "TABLE"

Tags: django, db2, db2-luw

I want the django to connect to db2 as another user (a DBADM) instead of db2inst1, the schema is XXX. but after running `python manage.py migrate`, it failed after creating tables DJANGO_MIGRATIONS and DJANGO_CONTENT_TYPE. They are both empty. The returned error is `[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0601N The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name "XXX.DJANGO_MIGRATIONS" of type "TABLE". SQLSTATE=42710`. I tried to drop tables and run the command again but failed. It seems it cannot find the DJANGO_MIGRATIONS table when trying to insert a new record so it tries to create it again. The command however succeeds when using db2inst1.

So I want to know if the issue is caused by insufficient user privileges? What privileges/roles the connection user should have? Are there any restrictions on the connection user? I tried to find document but couldn't find any.

Versions:
Django 3.2,
ibm-db-django 1.5.0.0,
ibm-db 3.1.0,
DB2 10.5

--Added database configuration in settings.py--

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'ibm_db_django',
        'CURRENTSCHEMA': 'XXX',
        'NAME': 'DBNAME',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'hostname',
        'PORT': '50000',
        'PCONNECT':  True,      #Optional property, default is false
    }
}
```

Comment: Works correctly for me when I configure to connect with an account that is not the db2-instance-owner.   I tested only with Db2 v11.1.4.6 because I currently do not have access to Db2 v10.5 but I doubt that matters.  Some configuration problem at your side. Show the (redacted) `settings.py` stanza for DATABASES by editing your question and adding plain text.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate error (SQL0601N) is caused by a previous run of `python manage.py` having begun (and possibly failed) for the **same** USER mentioned in the DATABASES stanza of the `settings.py`.

The ibm_db_django 1.5.0.0 ignores the CURRENTSCHEMA in the `settings.py` due to a coding defect, and the consequence is the symptom that you experience. For details of the defect and a code workaround, see this [link](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb-django/issues/68).

You will also experience a second problem (unrelated to the first) because you are using Db2-LUW v10.5, which does not have full support for BOOLEAN datatype, which instead got introduced at Db2-LUW v11.1, so consider upgrading your Db2-LUW server to V11.1 or V11.5 at latest fixpack.

While it is possible to hack the supplied migrations to avoid using BOOLEAN, it is for you to decide on the sustainability of that approach.

Keep in mind that IBM ended Db2 defect support for v10.5 on 30/April/2020, (no further fixes or enhancements) so unless your company already purchased extended support, then you should upgrade your Db2-LUW server anyway. If your company refuses to upgrade, you must decide whether your choice of toolset is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. My company refuses to upgrade the db unfortunately. I can create all the metadata tables using db2inst1 by modifying the scripts, changing boolean to char (though I'm not sure whether it is good). So far it is running well.  But if I try to runserver using another user, it reports `You have 28 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, dashboard, flatpages, redirects, sessions, sites....`  So I doubt if the issue is about user rights. I'll try the blank db first, thanks!

Comment: I created a blank db and it reports the same error. My steps: 1. db2inst1: `create database blank` 2. db2inst1: `GRANT DBADM ON DATABASE TO myuser` 3. myuser: `create schema XXX` 4. migrate => same error, both DJANGO_CONTENT_TYPE and DJANGO_MIGRATIONS tables are created with empty content.

Comment: It is workable if the schema name is the same as the user name. I think we will use this schema instead for saving time. Thanks for your help @mao !

Comment: Forgot to ask.. @mao, as you mentioned, if we're not able to upgrade the db, we must downgrade other components, may I know what is the updatest version for db2 10.5? Is "django 3.1 and ibm_db_django 1.4.0.0" compatible with our db?

Answer (score 0):

The error returns due to different CURRENTSCHEMA and USER:
https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb-django/issues/68

Comment: @Ike, that is what the first answer contains and it gives the same link.